# Approach to solving for the probability that a photo contains an object based on tags

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I've studied machine learning and statistics only very briefly. I've used linear regression to solve problems with fixed sets of variables, but I'm not sure how to approach the following problem.

Given a bunch of tagged photos, I'd like to use the tags to estimate the probability that a specific object is contained within the photo.

I have access to a wealth of data which has already been classified as either containing the objects we're looking for or not (however note that this is not a classification problem; the probabilities are being used to rank photos).

For example. If a photo is tagged with *coke* and *drink*, there is a high probability it contains coca-cola. However if a photo is tagged with *coke* and *crack*, there is a high probability it does not contain coca-cola. If a photo is tagged with either *crack* or *drink* separately, that doesn't tell us much about what might be in the photo.

How would one go about building a hypothesis formula for this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to model P(object in image | image, tags) or just P(object in image | tags)? I ask as even those these seem like related tasks, they would likely require very different approaches.

Comment: This is before we ever actually look at the image itself: P(object in image | tags)

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to try the following approach:

Each combination of 2 tags will have a weight value. Each 2-tag combination (using the tags appearing in the photo) will have a weight value calculated by the following formula:

(P(tag1 & tag2 | object exists in a photo)) ^ 2 - P(tag1 & tag2 | object does not exist in a photo) * P(tag1 & tag2)

The formula is somewhat experimental, but the first (squared) term represents the probability of finding the two tags in a photo containing the object, and the subtracted part has two multipliers, each representing a value that would work against the object appearing in the photo.

The sum of each of these weights is taken, and the result represents a "rank" score for the photo.